# T4 save template error

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I have created T4 template and when I save it I get the following errors:
what could be the problem

the code is 
and the error is because of assembly c:\net\ex....

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension="generated.cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity" #>

<#@ assembly name="C:\Net\Excesrise\Final\CodeGenWitht4Templates\bin\Debug\CodeGenWithT4Templates.exe" #>

<#@ assembly name="System.xml" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlServerCe" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity" #>
using System;

namespace Demo.Entities 
{    
  <#


                    var connectionString=@"data source=C:\Net\Excesrise\Final\CodeGenWitht4Templates\bin\Debug\CodeGenWithT4Templates.exe";

                        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open(); 
            System.Data.DataTable schema = conn.GetSchema("TABLES"); 
            string selectQuery = "select * from @tableName"; 
            var command = new SqlCeCommand(selectQuery,conn); 
            var ad = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command); 
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
            string currentTableName = String.Empty;

                        //PushIndent("          ");
            foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in schema.Rows) 
            { 
                currentTableName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                                currentTableName = currentTableName = currentTableName.Replace(" ", "");
                                currentTableName = currentTableName.Replace("[", "");
                                currentTableName = currentTableName.Replace("]", "");
            #> 
public class <#= currentTableName #>   {
<#                 
    command.CommandText = selectQuery.Replace("@tableName",row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()); 
    ad.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Mapped, row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());

    foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        var typeName = dc.DataType.Name;
        var propName = dc.ColumnName.Replace(dc.ColumnName[0].ToString(), dc.ColumnName[0].ToString().ToLower());
      propName = propName.Replace(" ", "");

        WriteLine ( "  public " + typeName + " " + propName + " {get;set;}" );                 
    }                 #>
 }                

      <#    
      }  #>  
}
```

**Error 1:**

> A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or
>   methods   C:\Net\Excesrise\Final\CodeGenWitht4Templates\ClassesFromDB.generated.cs

**Error 2**

> Compiling transformation: Metadata file
>   'C:\Net\Excesrise\Final\CodeGenWitht4Templates\bin\Debug\CodeGenWithT4Templates.exe'
>   could not be
>   found C:\Net\Excesrise\Final\CodeGenWitht4Templates\ClassesFromDB.tt  1   1   CodeGenWithT4Templates

**The Reason for the error i guess**

```
<#@ assembly name="C:\Net\Excesrise\Final\CodeGenWitht4Templates\bin\Debug\CodeGenWithT4Templates.exe" #>
```

....

Comment: Please show us the T4 template. It probably created a field or method outside of a class.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd- the code is added ,the problem is with the assembly i guess

Comment: Shouldn't this: `<#@ assembly name="C:\Net\Excesrise\Final\...` be escaped with a `@`? Also: does the generated cs file contain anything?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd- I already try to do it like this :<#@ assembly name=@"C:\Net\Excesrise\Final\CodeGenWitht4Templates\bin\Debug\CodeGenWithT4Templates.exe" #>    but I got error :A directive was specified in the wrong format. The transformation will not be run. Please specify the directive in the format <#@ name [parameterName="parameterValue"]*  #>

Comment: Correct, I mixed up the T4 and C# syntax. Is there anything in the generated C# file?

Comment: Are you missing `}` for `foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in schema.Rows)`?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd- Im just getting ErrorGeneratingOutput message

Comment: @OndrejJanacek- I tried to add one more after the loop and Im getting the same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second error: you don't need to reference your own **exe**. Because

1. Assembly directive is for assemblies, not executables
2. You use only standard classes
3. This exe is built using the output of your T4, recursion ?)

Also
Connection String to local database is not to your exe, it's like

```
 conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = MyDatabase.sdf; Password ='<pwd>'");
```

Rest of your code looks good. 
And Your first error is from a bad generated file, because it's like this

```
ErrorGeneratingOutput
```